# How to download the Release tar file from Github?

Tags: git, github

I have a project by name **TestProject** in Github and I have created a Release with version v1.0.0. Once I do that and when I go the release page of the project and I see 2 links to download `Source code (zip)` and other says `Source code (tar.gz)`.
Now I need to download this via `curl` so I copied the URL which looks like `https://github.com/../TestProject/archive/v1.0.0.tar.gz`.
When this files gets downloaded via `curl` its not a tar file cauz when I say `tar -zxvf v1.0.0.tar.gz` I get the below error message

> tar: Unrecognized archive format tar: Error exit delayed from previous
>   errors.

Now when I go the release page of Github and then click on the tar version, `TestProject-1.0.0.tar.gz` gets downloaded which is a tar file.

How do I get this file when I say `curl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add -L flag to the curl command in order to follow redirects.

example:

```
curl -O -L https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/archive/v3.9.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: What you said is correct but due to proxy issues I used the below command
curl -kLO --noproxy * https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/archive/v3.9.1.tar.gz